# Group by more than 2 columns in SharePoint 2013 in Data view Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, column, data-view-web-part, grouping

http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html this link which was mentioned earlier didnt worked out for me though i followed each and every step properly. Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the group by multiple column in query

```
string strQuery = "<GroupBy Collapse=\"TRUE\" GroupLimit=\"100\">" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Column Name\"/>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Column Name1\"/>" +
                    "</GroupBy>";
```

Note:- The Column you specify first will in grouping of the items and second will grouped on basis of first.

Comment: Where should i use this code? for the library aspx page?

Comment: How you are retrieving the records?

Comment: NO, only storing items , its a library

Comment: You must have added a dataview edit that view in browser and add two groupby fields and save it. Then open the page were you have added the dataview webpart in SharePoint designer. And find for word query and add you want in groupby tags.

Comment: You need to have xslt and apply groupby  on that and will work for you but it is not recommneded in SharePoint 2013
If you require i can share you the reference